# crossdomain.xml file at subdomains

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

This is my site: http://chfmm.ru/2 click at the SEAT and chose any seat. FireBug show error (http://s46.radikal.ru/i111/1010/60/1e43ff9e2bc7.jpg).
This photo hosting have 1 crossdomain file (http://www.radikal.ru/crossdomain.xml) 
what should I do?

my code:

```
Security.allowDomain("*"); 
            var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain); 
            context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain; 
            context.checkPolicyFile = true; 
            context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain; 


            imgItem.source = urlImgArray[0];
```

...

```
<mx:Image trustContent="true" loaderContext="{new LoaderContext(true)}" smoothBitmapContent="true" click="imgItem_clickHandler(event)" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" mouseChildren="false" id="imgItem" width="289" left="10" top="10" bottom="40"/>
```

Comment: Undefined questions have no answers..

Comment: when my code want to download the picture(s001.radikal.ru/myPhoto.jpg), he is checking crossdomain.xml in s001 subdomain(s001.radikal.ru/crossdomain.xml). But this hosting don't have this file in this subdomain. This hosting have this file in root (www.radikal.ru/crossdomain.xml)only. I want for my app check this file in ROOT only (not sub domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://s46.radikal.ru/crossdomain.xml is missing.  Try to add a policy there.

BTW: The http://www.radikal.ru/crossdomain.xml file is wide open, which can lead to possible security holes.

Comment: I can't add policy file to s46. This is no my hosting of pictures

Comment: Then you will need to load the images through a server proxy (mod_proxy, BlazeDS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The crossdomain file on http://www.radikal.ru/ is very permissive and will basically allow any domains, including of course any subdomains.

If anything, you will get a warning that the file's configuration is deprecated, this should not affect your data access.

Please give more information about what's happening, error messages etc...

Comment: first i catch this error(when i click at seat at my site): SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/Masonic.swf cannot access https://s001.radikal.com/somePic.jpg. A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded. at flash.display::Loader/get content()

Comment: And in fireBug: http://s46.radikal.ru/i111/1010/60/1e43ff9e2bc7.jpg Look at this picture

Comment: " A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded" , what do you mean?